# How to judge html's custom attribute has the one property in jquery

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes

I have define a custom attribute called "data-children",use as:

```
<div data-children=“test01 test02 test03”></div>
```

But how can I judge the property has "test04":

```
var $collection=$('div').attr('data-children')
……//then what can I do?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it returns a string, you can use the match method of the string object. I would suggest using the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data) method, though, if possible.

```
if ($('div').data('children').match(/(^|\s+)test04(\s+|$)/)) {
}
```

Comment: If you just want "does it match?" behaviour with your regex I suggest the [`.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) rather than `.match()`.